# adding hebrew value to sql using PDO

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

I am trying to add a Hebrew value to a database using php's PDO class.

After finally succeeding doing that 
(by using:  `array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"`), I found out that `COLLATE HEBREW_CI_AS` is added to my value.

Is there any way to prevent this addition?

thank you, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `set names` sets the charset for the client<->connection, but doesn't have any effect on the charset on the actual tables/fields.

Comment: set your columns to UTF8......you can set your tables to UTF8 as well but your existing columns wont change if you do that, so update all existing columns that need to be UTF8

Answer (score 0):

[PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8) is a good source of information on this.

Basically check whether your PDO-connection specifies the charset in the DSN:

```
new PDO(
    'mysql:host=your-hostname;dbname=your-db;charset=utf8',
    'your-username',
    'your-password',
    array(
        # ... PDO Connection Options
    )
);
```

Make sure your database tables are set to use the utf8-collation, either by phpmyadmin or using the mysql-command line utility and the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name COLLATE utf8;
```

Also you might want to consider using utf8mb4 as is suggested in the book.